# Find the most common attribute value from a List of objects using Stream

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have two classes that are structured like this:

```
public class Company {
     private List<Person> person;
     ...
     public List<Person> getPerson() {
          return person;
     }
     ...
}

public class Person {
     private String tag;
     ...
     public String getTag() {
          return tag;
     }
     ...
}
```

Basically the Company class has a List of Person objects, and each Person object can get a Tag value.

If I get the List of the Person objects, is there a way to use Stream from Java 8 to find the one Tag value that is the most common among all the Person objects (in case of a tie, maybe just a random of the most common)?

```
String mostCommonTag;
if(!company.getPerson().isEmpty) {
     mostCommonTag = company.getPerson().stream() //How to do this in Stream?
}
```

Comment: You can get a `Map` of `Company` to most used tag for that company using a `Stream` too. Also, no need for the `!company.getPerson().isEmpty()` etc.

Answer (score 31):

```
String mostCommonTag = getPerson().stream()
        // filter some person without a tag out 
        .filter(it -> Objects.nonNull(it.getTag()))
        // summarize tags
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getTag, Collectors.counting()))
        // fetch the max entry
        .entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        // map to tag
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(null);
```

**AND** the `getTag` method appeared twice, you can simplify the code as further:

```
String mostCommonTag = getPerson().stream()
        // map person to tag & filter null tag out 
        .map(Person::getTag).filter(Objects::nonNull)
        // summarize tags
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        // fetch the max entry
        .entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        // map to tag
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  One clarification though, I am getting an "element cannot be mapped to a null key" exception due to apparently some Person without a Tag value.  How should I handle this in the Stream.

Answer (score 7):

You could collect the counts to a Map, then get the key with the highest value

```
List<String> foo = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","e","e","f","f","f","g");
Map<String, Long> f = foo
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v, Collectors.counting()));
String maxOccurence = 
            Collections.max(f.entrySet(), Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)).getKey();

System.out.println(maxOccurence);
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work for you:

```
private void run() {
    List<Person> list = Arrays.asList(() -> "foo", () -> "foo", () -> "foo",
                                      () -> "bar", () -> "bar");
    Map<String, Long> commonness = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getTag, Collectors.counting()));
    Optional<String> mostCommon = commonness.entrySet().stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
    System.out.println(mostCommon.orElse("no elements in list"));
}

public interface Person {
    String getTag();
}
```

The `commonness` map contains the information which tag was found how often. The variable `mostCommon` contains the tag that was found most often. Also, `mostCommon` is empty, if the original list was empty.

Answer (score 5):

If you are open to using a third-party library, you can use [`Collectors2`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/collector/Collectors2.html) from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) with a Java 8 `Stream` to create a `Bag` and request the `topOccurrences`, which will return a `MutableList` of `ObjectIntPair` which is the tag value and the count of the number of occurrences.

```
MutableList<ObjectIntPair<String>> topOccurrences = company.getPerson()
        .stream()
        .map(Person::getTag)
        .collect(Collectors2.toBag())
        .topOccurrences(1);
String mostCommonTag = topOccurrences.getFirst().getOne();
```

In the case of a tie, the `MutableList` will have more than one result.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 3):

This is helpful for you,

```
Map<String, Long> count = persons.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getTag, Collectors.counting()));

Optional<Entry<String, Long>> maxValue = count .entrySet()
        .stream().max((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1).get().getKey();

maxValue.get().getValue();
```

Comment: This comparator does not handle equality - while this may work for `max`, it is usually not a good idea to do this - just use one of the numerous ways  to get an appropriate `Comparator`, e.g. via `Comparator.comparingLong`, `Long::compareTo`, [`Map.Entry.comparingByValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--)

Answer (score 3):

One More solution by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
// Comparing the solution by jdk stream, 
// there is no "collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getTag, Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream"
Stream.of(company.getPerson()).map(Person::getTag).skipNull() //
        .groupBy(Fn.identity(), Collectors.counting()) //
        .max(Comparators.comparingByValue()).map(e -> e.getKey()).orNull();

// Or by multiset
Stream.of(company.getPerson()).map(Person::getTag).skipNull() //
        .toMultiset().maxOccurrences().map(e -> e.getKey()).orNull();
```